# Utilizing Bash Completion in a script

Tags: bash, shell, tab-completion

I have a script which takes a UUID as the argument. When I run it manually I can access it using custom tab completion I have written. Is there a way of accessing this completion in a shell script?

```
~/myscript stop 0011<tab>
```

It will complete to:

```
~/myscript stop 0011-1111-1111-1111
```

Edit:
For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "~/myscript stop \t" | bash -i
```

The bash completion is already written. I'm currently executing it in another interactive shell, is there a way of executing this is the same shell?

Comment: When you are *writing* the script? Maybe, but that would be provided by your editor, not the shell.

Comment: `id` [command] in the script will do the work for you.. don't take arguments from outside

Comment: Are you asking whether you can run `~/myscript stop 0011-1111-1111-1111` and have myscript access the value `0011-1111-1111-1111`?

Comment: I'm working a python program which has bash completion enabled. When I access it via the terminal I am able to use the bash completion by starting the argument and pressing tab. However, if I put it into a shell script, I want to be able to access the same tab completion. Currently I'm accessing it by piping it into a new interactive shell. `echo "~/myscript stop 0011\t" | bash -i`

Comment: @Ashish [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) != user ID

Comment: It would somehow perhaps be less unnerving if your implementation was in Python and your Bash script would call Python, rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you can't just put the full UUID into your script. But I expect that you can do what you want to do using the bash `compgen` builtin.

I haven't played with `compgen` much and I've never used custom tab completion, so I can't give you detailed instructions, but using `compgen` to generate a list of possible filename completions is easy enough.

Eg, in my home directory,

```
compgen -f .ba
```

prints

```
.bash_history
.bashrc.dpkg-old
.bashrc
.bash_logout
.bashrc~
```

Comment: Ahh this is pretty useful, this is the what I was looking for. Wasn't really sure where to start with this one.